# Base class calls method from derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class BaseClass {
 public:
  virtual void method1(){
   method2();
  };
  virtual void method2(){
   std::cout << "Base Method" << std::endl;
  };
}

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
 virtual void method2(){
   std::cout << "Derived Method" << std::endl;
  };
}

int main() {
  DerivedClass derived;
  derived.method1();
}
```

In the above example I get "Derived Method" as the output - Why does this happen?

I understand that `DerivedClass` inherits from `BaseClass`, and therefore `derived` can call `method1`, but I don't understand why `method2` from `DerivedClass` hides `method2` from `BassClass` when it is being called from `BaseClass`.

Apologies for any bad code/mistakes - still new to C++.

Comment: That's what C++ is designed to do.

Comment: Because `BaseClass::method2()` is declared `virtual`.

Comment: This is an OOP principle, have you heard of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `method2` is `virtual`.

When you declare a function as `virtual`, what you're really doing is making it so that when the method is called via a pointer or reference (in other words, in a normal way) the function that is actually called is the most-derived overload.

This is a Good Thing, and usually exactly what you want.  Note that it doesn't matter from what context you make the call.  Your'e calling `method2` from the context of the base class, which has an implementation of `method2` available.  Presumably, you're assuming that since your calling from the base class that the base class' implementation is the one that will be called.

That's not how `virtual`s work -- and that's also a Good Thing.

You can, if you wish, call the version in the base class by being explicit about it:

```
class BaseClass {
 public:
  virtual void method1(){
   BaseCLass::method2();
  };
```

But this is usually not desirable, and in my book, a code smell.

Answer (score 2):

`derived.method1()` statically binds the function call `BaseClass::method1()`, however this function calls the virtual function `method2()`.  This causes dynamic binding to `DerivedClass::method2()` instead of calling `BaseClass::method2()`.

If you want to statically bind `BaseClass::method2()` in `BaseClass::method1()`, you must do this:

```
class BaseClass {
 public:
  virtual void method1(){
   BaseClass::method2(); //explicit class scope prevents dynamic binding
  }
  virtual void method2(){
   std::cout << "Base Method" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

Comment: Technically, even `derived.method1()` is a dynamic call as `method1` is `virtual`, but it can easily be resolved at compile time with certain compiler optimizations. Not many compilers do that though.

Comment: No, we know `derived` is a `DerivedClass`, not a reference or a pointer to one.  If `derived` were a sliced `DerivedClass` from something that inherited from `DerivedClass`, the virtual table pointer would point to somewhere that assumes it is `DerivedDerivedClass` and attempt to use data members it doesn't have.  Therefore, it must statically bind.

Comment: @pmr Actually I'm wrong about the slicing; gcc 4.8.2 seems to reassign the virtual table pointer to the class that you are slicing to.  For example, if `A` inherits from `B`, and `B` is sliced to `A`, the new object's virtual table pointer is reassigned to `A`'s stuff, not `B`.  So yes, `method1()` could also be dynamically bound. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Because you declared it virtual. If you don't want that behavior, remove the virtual declaration. Virtualization is vital to the whole notion of inheritance and object oriented programming. See "*The C++ Programming Language (Special Edition)*" chapter 12 for an in depth discussion.

Comment: "Delcared 'it' virtual."  Specify what "it" is, namely `method2()`.  `method1()` can still be virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `virtual` keyword from `method2()` of `BaseClass`. 
This will give you output as  "**Base Method**". This is static binding and as `method1` of `BaseClass` is called, so is `method2` of `BaseClass` called.

In contrast, virtual member functions are resolved dynamically (at run-time). That is, the member function is selected dynamically (at run-time) based on the type of the object. So an object of `DerivedClass` will always call `method2` of derived class only and output will be "**Derived class**".